# How does php store session values in cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, encryption, session-variables

After enabling the session I stored some values in SESSION variable. After that when I listed the cookies I came to see

> PHPSESSID=e95faec5rvtnnoooln8q0av504

How can I regenerate this value if I know the data I inserted in the Cookie variable? Which algorithm is PHP using to encrypt the cookie?

Comment: PHP __doesn't__ store session variables in a cookie.... the cookie is an ID for the session on the server.... by default, there will be a file called `e95faec5rvtnnoooln8q0av504` in the `/tmp` folder of your server that actually holds the session data